# Database Backup with only last 15 days data from all tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with data from 3 years in it with 100 tables. Say for example Tbl-1 to Tbl-100.

Now I need to get a backup with only last 15 days data from each table.

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: No, SQL Server does not have a concept of "15 days data". If you need something like that, you'll have to manually delete the other data.

Comment: Oh...
Thanks @JamesZ

Comment: Or use something such as BCP to write the data from the last 15 days into files. Or write the last 15 days into a new database and back that up.